# Project in Django: I can't create superuser in terminal to manipulate data in Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am doing a project with Django in which I try to change the database from SQLITE to Postqresql. When I try to create the super user I get this error.

**Traceback**

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 163, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 146, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 774, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\l\Desktop\django-course\Django(02-09-21)\crm1\accounts\signals.py", line 7, in customer_profile
    group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\l\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
```

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DEMO_TEST',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD':'12345678abcdef',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import SET_NULL
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='profile1.png',null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
            ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
            ) 
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    prince = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

The project works normally when I turn on the Django server; the problem is when i try to create superuser from terminal. I'm not sure if the problem comes from the connection between the Postgresql database with the project, or if it is some migration problem of the models created and loaded in Django's default database (SQLITE). I already tried doing the migrations again with the `makemigration` and `migrate` commands but the error persists when trying to create the superuser... Some help would be excellent, Thank you very much

Comment: It means a group that probably existed in the sqlite does not exist in the PostgreSQL database. The migrations will create tables, etc. but it will not copy/move *data* from the sqlite to the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: how can i fix it? Because i want to create the superuser @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please do *not* put everything in boldface. You should only use boldface to stress a small amount of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a signal handler `customer_profile` that tries to fetch a `Group` with name `customer`. But that group has not been created in the PostgreSQL database.

You can replace `Group.objects.get(…)` with: `Group.objects.get_or_create(…)`:

```
def customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwagrs):
    if created:
        __, group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='customer')
        instance.groups.add(group)
        Customer.objects.create(
                user = instance,
                name = instance.username
            )
        print('Profile created.!')
```